# Querying customers by phone number using the Netsuite Rest API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, axios, netsuite

I am trying to create a request to the NetSuite REST API and in my particular use case the most readily available source of information is the customers number.

I have an `axios` helper setup to make requests through. Was wondering if anyone could help me... This is what I have so far.

```
    await ns.get('customer?q=phone')
  .then((res) => {
     console.log(res)
     console.log('success')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
     console.log('error')
  })
```

Now unfortunately this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Found my solution!

```
    await ns.get('customer?q=phone IS <Customer Number Here>')
  .then((res) => {
      console.log('success')
      let custID = res.data.items[0].id
      console.log(custID);
      await ns.get(`customer/${custID}`)
         .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
         })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
     console.log('error')
  })
```

This code returned a very large object. Opening up response.data.items gave me the ID of the customer. Then making a new request with this id gave me the information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:** Remove `await` keyword.

```
 ns.get('customer?q=phone')
  .then((res) => {
     console.log(res)
     console.log('success')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
     console.log('error')
  })
```

**Otherwise**, you have to define the `async` to be able to use `await` like this

```js
var getData = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve("Your data"));

async function run(){
  try{
    var res = await getData();// ns.get('customer?q=phone')
     console.log(res);
     console.log('success');
  }catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
     console.log('error')
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I have already wrapped my code in async. I believe the issue with my code is specifically the query. What I believe I need to change is the
('customer?q=phone) I've tried something like ('customer?q=phone IS xxxx) but this did not work :( . 

Perhaps I need to learn how to query using SuiteQL